# Modifying GCSettings.IsServerGC

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, garbage-collection

I have a C# application that loads by default in workstation GC mode. This application loads various libraries via reflection. If a certain library is loaded, I'd like to use server GC instead of workstation GC. Is this possible? I tried adding it to the library's app.config file and it doesn't do anything, which seems to mesh with this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx

> This element can be used only in the application configuration file.

So am I out of luck here, or is there another way to enable server GC?

Comment: You cannot switch on-the-fly.  Otherwise obvious from IsServerGC only having a getter and not a setter.  Nor does a library have an app.config file, it only applies to the EXE.

Answer (score -1):

Use the App.config file like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As the question states, this is not a solution. The question was whether or not it is possible to switch to server on the fly, not via config, and the answer was "no".

Comment: Answer is still useful for those of us googling.